# Requisição AJAX retornando erro 404 ao invés de 429

Tags: jquery, ajax

Estou usando uma API pública que tem um limite de **3 requisições por minuto**.

Quando ultrapasso esse limite, era pra retornar o erro **429** (segundo a documentação). Estou tentando fazer a tratativa desse erro, exibindo uma mensagem pro usuário.

O problema é que após enviar a requisição pela 4ª vez, o erro que sempre é retornado é o **404** ao invés do **429**.

Código que estou usando pra fazer a requisição:
https://jsfiddle.net/ldias_digital/38thowyL/

[image: print do fiddle linkado]

Como resolver isso?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41683833/jquery-ajax-catch-status-code-errors#answer-41684090

Comment: Sabia que no Brasil todas essas APIs de consulta publico governamental que são comercializadas no mercado em maioria são apenas gateways para APIs disponibilizadas no [Catálogo de APIs Governamentais](https://www.gov.br/conecta/catalogo/)

Comment: Sim @AugustoVasques , porém não são APIs públicas, certo? Pelo que pude ver precisa fazer todo um requerimento para ter acesso ao uso...

Comment: @AugustoVasques no teste que fiz sempre retorna 429 a partir da quarta tentativa, inclusive comentei isso para o AP na outra pergunta que fez sobre o mesmo assunto, o problema não está sendo reproduzível.

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento vc pode ver o erro reproduzível aqui https://jsfiddle.net/ldias_digital/38thowyL/ e na imagem q acrescentei na pergunta

Comment: O console tá exibindo o status corretamente, 429, olha ai no print mesmo q voce mandou, quem tá errando é mandando 404 é o jquery, pode ser bug

Comment: Como esta postagem é duplicada, estou limitando os comentários para evitar ficar orientação em dois lugares (caso precise do campo de comments pode restaurar a original, lá o espaço está habilitado). Segue link para a original: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/555364/ - De qualquer forma, nenhuma pode ser reaberta, pois suporte de API de terceiros não cabe aqui. As perguntas precisam ter um [mcve] que não dependa de links, em especial ainda mais de intermediadores não oficiais.